# React component icon on click to show a popup-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onclick, components

I am attempting to create a page that shows the user's messages in React, and I want to implement an icon that when clicked on will show a popup form to send a new message to another user.

I have tried to implement a state and change state when the icon is clicked, showing the form and triggering the showForm function, though when I click on the icon nothing happens - no message is logged and nothing seems to get called.

MessageList.js:

```
const MESSAGING_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/messages';
const SEND_MESSAGE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/messages/send-message';
class MessageList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showForm: false, messages: [], token: '', topic: '', message: '', recipientUsername: '', username: localStorage.getItem("username")};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const payload = {
            "username": this.state.username,
            "password": localStorage.getItem("password")
        };
        fetch(MESSAGING_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
    showForm = () => {
        console.log("showForm fired")
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Recipient Username:
                        <input
                            name="recipientUsername"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.recipientUsername}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Topic:
                        <input
                            name="topic"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.topic}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Message:
                        <input
                            name="message"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.message}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const payload = {
            "username": this.state.username,
            "recipient-username": this.state.recipientUsername,
            "topic": this.state.topic,
            "message": this.state.message
        };
        fetch(SEND_MESSAGE_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({messages: data}));
    }


    render() {
        const {messages, isLoading} = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        const messageList = messages.map(message => {
            return <tr key={message.messageId}>
                <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{message.senderUsername}</td>
                <td>{message.recipientUsername}</td>
                <td>{message.topic}</td>
                <td>{message.message}</td>
            </tr>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <AppNavbar/>
                <Container fluid>
                    <i className="fas fa-plus" onClick={() => this.setState({showForm: true}) }></i>
                    <button  onClick={() => this.setState({showForm: true}) }>Add New Application</button>
                    <h3>Messages</h3>
                    <Table className="mt-4">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="25%">Sender Username</th>
                            <th width="25%">Recipient Username</th>
                            <th width="25%">Topic</th>
                            <th width="25%">Message</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {messageList}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default MessageList;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're rendering the popup anywhere. In the return of the render method `{this.state.showForm === true && this.showForm()}`

Comment: @a.mola Thanks for the response, sorry I have taken so long to respond. For the code you have commented, I put it inside the onClick={} at this <button onClick={this.state.showForm === true && this.showForm()}>Add New Application</button>

Comment: @a.mola However, I now get this error: Uncaught TypeError: func.apply is not a function                           Thanks.

Comment: Don't put the code in the button's onClick prop, put it where you want the form to be rendered. i.e somewhere in the component's render return function.